# Service onStartCommand being called once activity ends

Tags: android

I start my service when I click the play button to play a song and bundle the song mp3 with it and receive that in the onStartCommand. The problem is that when my activity that starts the service ends, my service calls onStartCommand again. When it goes to receive that bundle it's not there because the activity did not start it this time. Because of this I'm getting an illegalstateexception when preparing my mediaplayer. I am not binding my service.

Why does the onStartCommand get called when my activity ends?

Starting the service:

```
Intent i = new Intent(SongList.this,MyService.class);
i.putExtra("songURL", user.songurlz);
i.putExtra("songNAME", songplay_name);
startService(i);
```

The service class:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    static int pauseplay;
    static NotificationManager notificationManagerPlay;
    static CharSequence tickerText;
    static Notification notification4;//Notification variable(for song playing)
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
    PhoneStateListener listener;
    static Notification notification;
    static NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    String songurl;
    String songname;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        pauseplay = 1;
        MainMenu.serviceRunning = 1;
        telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(
                Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        // Create a new PhoneStateListener
        listener = new PhoneStateListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying() == true && mediaPlayer != null){
                        pauseSong();
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        };
        // Register the listener wit the telephony manager
        telephonyManager.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        if (intent != null) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            //Retrieve your data using the name
            songurl = bundle.getString("songURL");
            Bundle bundle2 = intent.getExtras();
            //Retrieve your data using the name
            songname = bundle2.getString("songNAME");
        }
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Now Playing: "
                + songname, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        // configure the intent
        Intent playIntent = new Intent(MyService.this, SongList.class);
        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                MyService.this, 0, playIntent, 0);
        notification = new Notification(R.drawable.playicon, "Buffering...",
                System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
                R.layout.custom_notification2);
        notification.contentIntent = pendingIntent;
        if (SongList.bitmap != null) {
            notification.contentView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.notifimage,
                    SongList.bitmap);
        } else {
            notification.contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.notifimage,
                    R.drawable.icon);
        }
        notification.contentView
                .setTextViewText(R.id.notiftitle, "Now Playing");
        notification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notiftext, songname);
        notification.flags = notification.flags
                | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(4, notification);
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(songurl);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // register an error listener via MediaPlayer's setOnErrorListener
        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                Log.e("MEDIAPLAYER ERRORS", "what: " + what + "  extra: "
                        + extra);
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mNotificationManager.cancel(4);
                return false;
            }
        });
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
        mediaPlayer
                .setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){

                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        stopSelf();
                    }
                });
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        MainMenu.serviceRunning = 0;
        mNotificationManager.cancel(4);
    }

    public static void pauseSong() {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying() == true) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            mNotificationManager.cancel(4);
            pauseplay = 0;
        }
    }

    public static void playSong() {
        if (pauseplay == 0) {
            mNotificationManager.notify(4, notification);
            mediaPlayer.start();
            pauseplay = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why does the onStartCommand get called when my activity ends?

Either you are calling `startService()` when your "activity ends" (whatever that means), or Android is restarting your service for some reason due to your use of `START_STICKY`.

Personally, for a music player, I argue that `START_NOT_STICKY` is the right answer. If your service is stopped for whatever reason, the user should be in charge of starting it up again.

Comment: I will try START_NOT_STICKY, maybe I have misunderstood the terms. I mean when using the back button to close the app the music stops and the app force closes. It looks like the service tries to start back up after the activity is ended and the Bundle.getIntents become null

Comment: So this solved my force closing problem, but when I click play and then back button to leave the app, the music stops playing. The notification that disappears on service destroy stays there.

Comment: I'm on custom ICS ROM Samsung Galaxy S Vibrant ICS Passion

Comment: @NickNelson: Something is calling `stopService()` when your activity is paused, stopped, or destroyed.

Comment: In that case the notification would disappear, but it doesn't. It stays in the status bar.

Answer (score 3):

I know that this answer might not be useful anymore, but I had the same issue and by checking the documentation of [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_REDELIVER_INTENT) return code for `onStartCommand` I found that it will solve the issue.

EDIT:

Your `onStartCommand should` be like this:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    //the same code
    //......
    //then return the new code which I'm pointing to
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
```

Here's what the documentation say about this return code:

```
public static final int START_REDELIVER_INTENT
```

> Constant to return from `onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)`: if this service's process is killed while it is started (after returning from
>   `onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)`), then it will be scheduled for a restart and the last delivered Intent re-delivered to it again via
>   `onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)`.

Using this return code will make the OS resend the Intent every time the method `onStartCommand` recalled (for whatever reason might cause this).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.