# keeping background service alive after user exit app

Tags: android, service, android-service, background-service

I'm trying to create a service that will do background jobs for me even after the user closes the app from the running processes menu(by shifting process out of the screen).

What I tried to do is create service in a different process by declaring it like this:

```
  <service
        android:name=".service.Service"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:process=":my_process" >
  </service>
```

and the onStartCommand() is:

```
    @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: Hi, have you come into a solution? I've been searching for hours to solve this issue, and I wasn't able to come to a solution.
Your code looks exactly like mine.

Comment: I have solved this by simply starting my service using this line: 
`ContextWrapper cont = new ContextWrapper(getBaseContext());
   cont.startService(service);`

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651009/android-service-stops-when-app-is-closed

Comment: if you show a notification from that service, it will prevent os from killing it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html#isolated) you can achieve this behavior by using the attribute:

```
 android:isolatedProcess="true"
```

By the way, I know that it's not answering the question but it might help some people as well - lately, I found out about a great third-party lib that Evernote developers have created. Its name is [Android-Job](https://github.com/evernote/android-job) and its aim is to create jobs that run on different processes and can become active again even after a device reboot, it's amazing.

Comment: This library is very old. Will it be fine to use it?

Comment: Yes we are using it extensively. Not sure but i think it gets new commits every now and than

Comment: Looks like the service is not even getting started after adding isolatedProcess=true on Oreo :(

Comment: is ti still work for latest android versions ?

Comment: @Ahmad Sorry for the late response. I have no idea. I abandoned this project years ago

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are different kinds of services you can implement. Use a Service instead of `IntentService`. There you need to look at `START_STICKY` , `START_NOT_STICKY` and `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` you can keep your service running in background even if your activity dies. [Android services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) also look at `AIDL` services

Comment: I used `START_REDELIVER_INTENT`, but my service still stops when user closes the app.

Comment: I used `START_STICKY`,but my service still stops even the app is force closed by user.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use Handler and Runnable class

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {

        Toast.makeText(context, "SMS SERVICE START", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        handler=new Handler();
        runnable=new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {

                    TASK();
                    handler.postDelayed(runnable,180000);
// 3min delay
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(runnable,180000);
        super.onCreate();
    }
```

This task run continuously 3min

```
public void TASK()
{
     //your task 

}
```

Answer (score -8):

Services were designed to run in the background, no need for a different process.

From the services documentation:

> Once started, a service can run in the background indefinitely, even if the component that started it, is destroyed.

The service however, should stop itself, when its work is done. [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingIntentService) is the easiest way to start implementing a service.

Comment: Yeah I saw this line but still, every time when I close the app the service being distroyed also. By the way, I don't know if it matters but the service implement OnSensorListener to listen to accelometers changes(movements..)

Comment: @powerX How do you start the service? Are you binding to it or with `startService`?

Comment: I'm using startService with intent in order to start my service

Comment: @powerX Sorry, no idea then.