# Service stops when I exit my app

Tags: android, android-service

I have an application with a service. Service is started by an app in the main activity on create method. My problem occurs when I exit from the application: service stops

Manifest File

```
<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:isolatedProcess="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".DialActivity">
    </activity>
    <service
        android:name=".ButtDial.CallDetectService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />

    <activity android:name=".Utils.IncomingCallActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Utils.OutGoingCallActivity"></activity>
    <receiver
        android:name=".ButtDial.CallHelper$OutgoingReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="RestartServiceWhenStopped">

    </receiver>
</application>
```

I don't know how to initiate my service when an app exit
Service

```
public class CallDetectService extends Service {
private CallHelper callHelper;

public CallDetectService() {
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    callHelper = new CallHelper(this);

    int res = super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    callHelper.start();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    callHelper.stop();
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // not supporting binding
    return null;}
public class MyBinder extends Binder {
    public CallDetectService getService() {
        return CallDetectService.this;
    }
}}
```

In Activity

Please help me for this issue

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CallDetectService.class);
startService(intent);
```

Comment: Are you killing the process or using System.exit(0)? Use finishAffinity() in order to resume your service.

Comment: On which OS version are you running your app?

Comment: yeah, I will Kill the App by Task Manager, But i have to run my service in background.How to do ? @SarthakGandhi

Comment: When you kill your app from task manager it kills the process. If you want to run the service again you can add a broadcast reciever.

Comment: In Nougat Version, in kitKat its working..higher than that..wasn't @Sagar

Comment: In Android Oreo this is expected behavior. Nougat is strange

Comment: I implemented a broadcast receiver.Even though it wasn't working@SarthakGandhi

Comment: The real question is what SDK API you target?

Comment: Any Ideas ? @Sagar

Comment: SDK 28 @ZachBublil

Comment: That's the problem my friend, your app acts like it runs on Oreo OS, try to change it to 25

Comment: Changed to Target SDK 25. Even though it's not working@ZachBublil

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:stopWithTask="false"` in manifest as bellow, This means even if user kills app by removing it from `tasklist`, your `service` won't stop.

```
 <service
   android:name="CallDetectService "
   android:stopWithTask="false"
   android:isolatedProcess="true"/>
```

for more have look [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37317413/5110595)
Hope it will help you!!

Comment: That's a good idea thought, but I don't think it will help if you target 26+ APIs levels. Would it?

Comment: before call service make sure permission is granted, than call service.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you manage to find some way to execute on Android N, the approach won't work from Android O which has imposed several restriction on background services. You won't be able to freely run or start the Services. When app enters background, Service will be stopped as if `stopSelf()` is called.

If its crucial for you to ensure Service runs to completion, even if app is closed, then you can create ForegroundService. This approach will also work on Android O. You can follow my answer on this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51241184/background-service-is-not-working-in-oreo/51241791#51241791) for implementation details.

Comment: Thanks, Kindly say where to place foreground in Service Class @Sagar

Comment: @kirubhasankar you need to call it in `onCreate()`. Create notification and when you start the service, `ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, serviceIntent)`