# Service not running after closing app

Tags: java, android, notifications, background-service

I am trying to make background service that will run 15 sec after user closes tha app, I have done service that runs 15 sec (loop with Logs), bud when I close tha app, then it stopes

and another problem is, when I try to stop it from main activity by `stopService(intent)`; then the `onDestroy` method is called, but thread with loop continues

.. please can someone help me?

*sorry for my english - no native :D

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {
    final private class MyThread implements Runnable {

        int service_id;

        MyThread(int service_id) {
            this.service_id = service_id;
        }


        @Override
        public void run() {

            synchronized (this) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                    try {
                        wait(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.e("onStartCommand", "loop:" + i);
                }
                stopSelf(service_id);
            }
        }
    }

    Thread thread;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(@Nullable Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e("onStartCommand", "started");
        Toast.makeText(this, "onStartCommand", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        thread = new Thread(new MyThread(startId));
        thread.start();

        return START_STICKY;
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.e("onDestroy", "onDestroy");
        Toast.makeText(this, "onDestroy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you making sure the Service is being started just as the app is closed?

Comment: for now I am calling the service by pressing button, latter the app will play short video and the close itself ( not sure how exactly I am going to do this :D )

Comment: please see my answer below, clicking a button only works if the app is not closed...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Service Stops When App Is Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651009/android-service-stops-when-app-is-closed)

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to make background service that will run 15 sec after user closes tha app, I have done service that runs 15 sec (loop with Logs), bud when I close tha app, then it stopes

Your code only starts the loop thread when `startService(yourNotificationService)`is called on the `Activity` or `Broadcast Receiver`that is responsible for calling it does so. It then kills itself with `stopSelf(service_id)`.

If, after you have returned from `onStartCommand()`, you immediately kill the app without calling `stopSelf(service_id)` (i.e. your 15 seconds is not up), then your Service will MOST LIKELY restart itself given the `START_STICKY` return value. However, after you call `stopSelf(service_id)` you are telling the Service to kill itself; after you close your app, there is nothing to tell your Service to restart through the `onStartCommand()` call.

> and another proble is, when I try to stop it from main activity by stopService(intent); then the onDestroy method is called, but thred with loop continues

A `Service` is an Android component; it is **not** another process or thread, it runs in the same process and thread as the main UI thread unless you specify otherwise, as seen [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

> Note that services, like other application objects, run in the main thread of their hosting process. This means that, if your service is going to do any CPU intensive (such as MP3 playback) or blocking (such as networking) operations, it should spawn its own thread in which to do that work. More information on this can be found in Processes and Threads. The IntentService class is available as a standard implementation of Service that has its own thread where it schedules its work to be done.

In your case, calling `stopService(intent)` tells the `Service` to stop itself, which it does. It **does not** stop the `Thread` you started (the `MyThread` instance). To do that, you must first make your `Thread` interruptible; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961714/how-to-properly-stop-the-thread-in-java) to do that. Once you do that, you need to  change your `onDestroy()` code to actually interrupt the `MyThread` instance, as here

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.e("onDestroy", "onDestroy");
    Toast.makeText(this, "onDestroy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    thread.interrupt();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: thx ;), I am new to Android and Java .. just learning everything :D