# Background Service in Xamarin.Forms, iOS, Android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a background service in android.

My code is as follows:

```cs
[Service]
public class PeriodicService : Service
{
    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), () =>
             {
                 // code
              });
        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

}
```

The `MainActivity` class:

```cs
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
    LoadApplication(new App());

    StartService(new Intent(this, typeof(PeriodicService)));
}
```

Permission `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PeriodicService" />
```

The problem is that my service only works in the background when the app is active or in the foreground but when I close the app it doesn't run in the background.

Comment: By background do you mean: 1) when the app is closed, 2) when the app is navigated away from?

Comment: by background I mean when the app is closed. i want to implement a service that runs permanently in the background. and the service should work when the app is closed or open

Comment: @Mazen Hi, you can have a look at [Remote Processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/out-of-process-services) in Android . It will remain running even when app is killed .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT do you have a code example

Comment: @Mazen Sorry , I have no sample now . If have later will share here.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is to follow along with what Fabio has written in his post about how to create [The Never Ending Background Task](https://fabcirablog.weebly.com/blog/creating-a-never-ending-background-service-in-android).

The idea behind this is to create a BroadcastReceiver and Android Service in the manifest. The BroadcastReceiver will then activate the service with foreground priority as the application is being closed. If you are dealing with post Android 7 then he created an update to his blog showing [The Fix](https://fabcirablog.weebly.com/blog/creating-a-never-ending-background-service-in-android-gt-7).

Just to get a better understanding of how basic Android services operate, I'd recommend taking a look at this [Android Services Tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html)

I also saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651009/android-service-stops-when-app-is-closed) other StackOverflow post that seems to be pretty similar so maybe there will be some useful info over there too.

I'm not too acclimated in this stuff, but I was able to follow along with the blog posts pretty easily so I hope this ends up helping :). If anyone finds a better solution I'd love to hear about it so tag be (if you would be so kind) so I can stay updated!